# failing to call Semantic UI in javascript

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I want to create a tab UI element with Semantic UI.
I have the following code in my html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<h1>Braitenberg Playground</h1>
        <div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
            <a class="active item" data-tab="first">One</a>
            <a class="item" data-tab="second">Two</a>
            <a class="item" data-tab="third">Three</a>
        </div>

        <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="first">First</div>
        <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="second">Second</div>
        <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="third">Third</div>

<script>
$('.menu .item')
.tab()
;

</script>
</html>
```

The Tab UI is created but unfortunately, they are not activated when clicked. I can't figure out why that is

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine.  https://jsfiddle.net/85mm5uq7/

The issue is that you have a typo. :(

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

should be

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey man, 

I feel a bit stupid now. On the one hand because of the typo and on the other hand on the fact that it still doesn't work although I corrected the typo.
Am I missing something fundamental?

I'm using Sublime Text 3 and I'm running it through establishing localhost:8000 with the terminal and Chrome Browser on Mac

Comment: None of that should matter.  Do you have any console errors?

Comment: No errors or warnings. Strange thing is that all the other semantic ui components work just fine :/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by altering the js script.
It now explicitly adresses the tabs, setting it active/unactive on click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.ui .item').on('click', function() {
      $('.ui .item').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      var tab = $(this).attr("data-tab");
        $(".tab.segment").removeClass("active");
        $(".tab.segment[data-tab=\"" + tab + "\"]").addClass("active");
   });             
});
```

thanks for pointing out the typo in the beginning and for investing your time!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but perhaps can help someone. I get it working changing the order of jquery and semantic scripts. The jquery script must be imported first:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
```